# How to apply nested for loop within a lambda.apply function to iterate over columns within dataframe, expected output in the image below

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, apply

How to apply nested for loop within a lambda.apply function to iterate over columns within dataframe, expected output in the image below

```
import pandas as pd
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import smtplib

# Setup data
firstProductSet = {'Product1': ['Computer','Phone','Printer','Desk'],'Price1': [1200,800,200,350],'Price2': [11,11,11,11],'Price3': [1,800,1,1],'Price4': [111,111,11,111]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(firstProductSet,columns= ['Product1', 'Price1','Price2','Price3','Price4'])
```

Attempted result

```
result_2 = (df1.style.apply(lambda x:["color: red" if ((i == 3 and v != x.iloc[1]) or (i == 4 and v != x.iloc[2])) else "" for i, v in enumerate(x)], axis=1))

html=result_2.hide_index().render()
```

Comment: basically trying to have another for loop to check the column comparison dynamically instead of OR condition

Comment: df = {'Product1': ['Computer','Phone','Printer','Desk']
                    ,'Price1': [1200,800,200,350],'Price2': [11,11,11,11]
                    ,'Price3': [1,800,1,1],'Price4': [111,111,11,111]
                   }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df,columns= ['Product1', 'Price1','Price2','Price3','Price4'])
result = (df1.style.apply(lambda x:["color: red"
             if ((i == 3 and v != x.iloc[1])
                 or (i == 4 and v != x.iloc[2])) else ""
             for i, v in enumerate(x)], axis=1))
html=result_2.hide_index().render()
#send email to check formatiing

Comment: Please [edit] your sample data into the text of your question, comments are for discussion and clarification and don't show code well

Comment: had a hard time posting this ,